# Batch - .bat - Exclude directories in for loop

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a .bat file that loops through everything in a directory and compares the contents to what's in another directory. The first directory has more directories, but I want to ignore them in my loop:

```
rem Folders to Compare for similar files
set "DMZFolder=\\sc0189v\d$\APPS\Host_to_Host\ACHDH\DONE"
set "AMSFolder=D:\Apps\AMS\Files\Orig\UOB\BACKUP"

rem !!! I want it to ignore directories
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /b "%DMZFolder%"') do (
    if not exist "%AMSFolder%\%%F" (
         set /a count+=1       
    )
)
```

As my comments say, currently the count is incremented even if %%F is a directory. I only want this to happen for files.

Thanks.

Comment: You should open a Command Prompt window and enter `dir /?`. You may notice the `D` attribute and `-` prefix with the `/A` option. *However, it looks like you may be able to bypass all of that and just use `RoboCopy` and/or `FindStr` instead.*

Comment: @Compo - Why put a strong hint to the answer in a comment? This seems worthy of a full answer.

Comment: @ both of you: I thank Compo for enlightening me on how to get help from the command prompt, which led me to fix the problem, and dbenham for your concern as to me getting help. :)

Comment: Scott, I've rolled back your last edit. Please do not add answers to your question, use the answer area, to create a proper answer. @dbenham, because I felt this was a basic command option issue, and RTFM type answers shouldn't necessarily be posted, _(especially as it meant an addition of only four to six characters)_. It was easier to give the OP an opportunity to fix it themselves, if they didn't wish to use another method.

Comment: @Compo Ah, yes. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this instead:

```
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir/b/a-d "%DMZFolder%"') do (
```